# Not able to aply font weight in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to give font weight to my span as inline css.

```
interface Label {
    title: string;
    fontSize: string;
    fontColor: string;
    fontFamily: string;
    fontWeight: string;
}
const Label = (props:Label) => {
    return (
        <span style={{color:props.fontColor,fontSize:props.fontSize,fontFamily:props.fontFamily,fontWeight:props.fontWeight}}>{props.title}</span>
    )
}
```

It's giving me `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FontWeight`.
I am calling this component like

```
<Label title="SYNOASSESS" fontSize="30.1638px"  fontFamily="Futura" fontColor="#2789FC" fontWeight="bold" />
```

If i write

```
<span style={{color:props.fontColor,fontSize:props.fontSize,fontFamily:props.fontFamily,fontWeight:"bold"}}>{props.title}</span>
```

Then it's working fine but fontWeight is not working with props.

Comment: Are you sure u r using `fontWeight` and not `FontWeight` as in the error it shows `FontWeight` while ur using `fontWeight` everywhere

Comment: Looks like you have type `FontWeight`. So, string value can't be assigned to it without casting it.

Comment: Yes i am sure i am using fontWeight not FontWeight everywhere

Comment: Please check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS doesn't know more than `fontWeight` is a string. So need to do type casting.

```
interface LabelProps {
  title: string;
  fontSize: string;
  fontColor: string;
  fontFamily: string;
  fontWeight: string;
}

const Label = (props: LabelProps) => {
  const boldText = {
    fontWeight: props.fontWeight
  } as React.CSSProperties;

  return (
    <span
      style={{
        color: props.fontColor,
        fontSize: props.fontSize,
        fontFamily: props.fontFamily,
        fontWeight: boldText.fontWeight
      }}
    >
       {props.title}
    </span>
  );
```

> [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-villani-yvdvw?file=/src/App.tsx:328-489)

or you can wrap entire style object with React.CSSProperties.

```
const styles = {
  color:props.fontColor,
  fontSize:props.fontSize,
  fontFamily:props.fontFamily,
  fontWeight:props.fontWeight
 } as React.CSSProperties;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't understand 'fontWeigth'. You can look this [issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2026) to understand more. Can u try below code

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface Label {
    title: string;
    fontSize: string;
    fontColor: string;
    fontFamily: string;
    'font-weight': string;
}
const Label = (props:Label) => {
    return (
        <span style={{color:props.fontColor,fontSize:props.fontSize,fontFamily:props.fontFamily,fontWeight:props['font-weight']}}>{props.title}</span>
    )
}
function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Label title="SYNOASSESS" fontSize="30.1638px"  fontFamily="Futura" fontColor="#2789FC" font-weight="bold" />
      </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use this:

```
const styles = {color:props.fontColor,fontSize:props.fontSize,
fontFamily:props.fontFamily,fontWeight:props.fontWeight} as React.CSSProperties;
```

and then:

```
<span style={styles}>{props.title}</span>
```